# What is wrong with the following for loop syntax in Swift?

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift

Why it is showing error in for loop even after I have copied the code from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)?

And here is the here with issue.[image]

---

**EDIT: Added Code**
Here is my whole code in that class

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

class SignUpViewController2: UIViewController
{
    for let index = 0; index < 3; ++index
    {
        println("index is \(index)")
    }

    for let i = 0; i < 3; i++
    {
        print("HI")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
        {
            println("YES")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

---

**And here is the image with errors of whole class**
[image]

Comment: Nothing as i see. It worked for me. Which version of Xcode you are using? Also paste the whole function where you are using it.

Comment: i bet you have a syntax error in the lines before this statement.

Comment: Cleaned and restarted the xcode also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index
{
    println("hi")
}
```

This works for me in the playground.

As no bigger snipped of your code is available, I can only guess but one possible problem could be that you are trying this in a swift file. In that case please ensure that the loop is in a function and not outside in the class definition. I tried that and it was giving me the same errors but the errors go away when moved inside any function

EDIT:-

I see that you have added the code in the Class definition instead of in any particular functions. Please modify the code as follows:-

```
class SignUpViewController2: UIViewController
{
    func forLoops()
    {
        for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index
        {
            println("index is \(index)")
        }

        for var i = 0; i < 3; i++
        {
            print("HI")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
        {
            println("YES")
        }
        forLoops()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

This will work now. You must put all your loops and executable statements in a function. Only include property declarations/definitions and functions in your class definition.

Hope this helped.

EDIT2:- Problem 2 was that you had written your for loops with a constant instead of a variable. Please change

```
for let index = 0; index < 3; ++index
{
    println("index is \(index)")
}
```

to

```
for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index
{
    println("index is \(index)")
}
```

You cannot change a value of a constant which is why it was giving problems at the increment operator.

Comment: I have added a reason at the bottom for why it might not work based on my own observations. Why don't we wait for OP to respond?

Comment: Because you don't actually answer the question (due to it not being clear), you ask for more information. On StackOverflow, this is done via comments rather than answers.

Comment: Why do you think this could not be a possible answer? >> "Are you trying this in the playground or in a swift file? If it is in a swift file, please ensure that the loop is in a function and not outside in the class definition. I tried that and it was giving me the same errors but the errors go away when moved inside any function"

Comment: If OP does clarify, I will edit the answer to include any changes that might be relevant. If it does get one more delete vote though, I will delete it

Comment: If you edit it to something like *"As no bigger snipped of your code is available I can only guess. But one possible solution could be..."* and leave out the *"Are you trying this in the playground or in a swift file?"* that would change things. That way there would only be an answer and no questions connected.

Comment: Yes, that's better. :) I don't think I can take my vote back but I doubt any others will come in now.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs blalasaadri. @developer please check my updated answer

Comment: @RajeevBhatia: Still same issue!

Comment: Are you facing the same issue after moving the for loops to the forLoops() function? What is the exact error you are facing now? Please also post a screenshot of the updated code on imgur and post the link here

Comment: I see what problem you have done. Please change your let to var in the for loops. Let me update the answer

Comment: @Rajeev Bhatia It worked after enclosing the loops in a function and changing let to var! Thanks a lot! Where did you read this??

"You must put all your loops and executable statements in a function."

Comment: My pleasure and thanks for accepting as answer! I will modify my statement to  "You must put all your loops and executable statements in FUNCTIONS." ...I have not officially read this anywhere but all the object oriented languages I have used so far(about 5 or 6) only allow you to add functions and variables in the class body and executable statements must be added inside functions so that's where I came up with that statement!